# Fetching "Special Hours" from Google Business

Tags: web-services, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

A Place Details response using the Google Places API only includes normal operating hours, not special hours. When you “download all locations” from the Google Business UI in CSV format, there is a row titled “special hours” with the data I want to retrieve. So I know it's there. See an example of this at the following published Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR9lrELXbbiDw9QLeVEo-Ob6JH2hf5YuI2vRjQ9mPASMFfiXlLKPUSf98GkjN87h--y2f7DgVx0lFhE/pubhtml

**Is it possible to retrieve “Special Hours” information from Google Business using the Google Places API Web Service or is this only possible by using the Google Business API?**

A parameter titled "special hours" exists in the Google Business API Documentation.

```
//JSON example for a Place Details Response using Google Places API Web service
        {
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "result" : {
              "address_components" : [
                 {
                    "long_name" : "San Luis Obispo",
                    "short_name" : "San Luis Obispo",
                    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                 },
                 {
                    "long_name" : "San Luis Obispo County",
                    "short_name" : "San Luis Obispo County",
                    "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                 },
                 {
                    "long_name" : "California",
                    "short_name" : "CA",
                    "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                 },
                 {
                    "long_name" : "United States",
                    "short_name" : "US",
                    "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                 },
                 {
                    "long_name" : "93407",
                    "short_name" : "93407",
                    "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                 }
              ],
              "adr_address" : "Building 65, 1 Grande Ave, \u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eCalifornia Polytechnic State University\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eSan Luis Obispo\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eCA\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e93407\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUSA\u003c/span\u003e",
              "formatted_address" : "Building 65, 1 Grande Ave, California Polytechnic State University, San Luis Obispo, CA 93407, USA",
              "formatted_phone_number" : "(805) 756-4089",
              "geometry" : {
                 "location" : {
                    "lat" : 35.30001179999999,
                    "lng" : -120.6586874
                 }
              },
              "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
              "id" : "f70e2b28dda6dbf04550b76db802f20fe1f79d5c",
              "international_phone_number" : "+1 805-756-4089",
              "name" : "Mustang Station",
              "opening_hours" : {
                 "open_now" : false,
                 "periods" : [
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 0,
                          "time" : "2300"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 0,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 1,
                          "time" : "2300"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 1,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 2,
                          "time" : "2300"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 2,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 3,
                          "time" : "2300"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 3,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 4,
                          "time" : "2300"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 4,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 6,
                          "time" : "0000"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 5,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "close" : {
                          "day" : 0,
                          "time" : "0000"
                       },
                       "open" : {
                          "day" : 6,
                          "time" : "1030"
                       }
                    }
                 ],
                 "weekday_text" : [
                    "Monday: 10:30 AM – 11:00 PM",
                    "Tuesday: 10:30 AM – 11:00 PM",
                    "Wednesday: 10:30 AM – 11:00 PM",
                    "Thursday: 10:30 AM – 11:00 PM",
                    "Friday: 10:30 AM – 12:00 AM",
                    "Saturday: 10:30 AM – 12:00 AM",
                    "Sunday: 10:30 AM – 11:00 PM"
                 ]
              },
              "photos" : [
                 {
                    "height" : 2340,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112622063888784238324/photos\"\u003eJana Isabel Gervacio\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAGZsi0QehA7q1gTjAThJgTUtDSkkGaL4Xk_x01RkN6t8HfoABoLGl45Gpo_bznS4sI4OKag40IWiCsbq8J-naZ-9YwQ4iZ9H1YrFEBTMdlTWoxnW0uxpABT-2JKn6D7q38yQP5lznOlL7RmghoNxwbSvB6TDk45iwDLMSce-JBPcEhDLAcpTdUku3To8HxDhhszlGhRwBi5muKEn_68_MOAnjx0MLbSBJw",
                    "width" : 4160
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3840,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAB0VKDa1mNnEVRpWtjg8lbM3zONoyqai_LmUB41fP7FtprCairVIzw_QBpKix4ZNOn6swUgNf8C907X0bv8SnMktdacFV_aSy6sOFogdRPveXCBx84p2wrVH95GwTpk0lsNhzLovPuk9oZ39nH1U7XdP3LUfdNWQL2XCgUBqlkICEhDqaRdvjIG9gdp5gUWVfSAMGhRG75JyhhhqUxyZAU62IP_z-oMj7A",
                    "width" : 5760
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3456,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAEb9o0hItdL5eswLOgmJH9EOGNlqfWbjkcwhv9Aqk9yPbqAIhrTkeyun9r-G38kxcpO7QW3hD_MNtik07JAFhY2oY4fXuEeE1pKeAq7faNNytgQDCG37vh_LRqAVEaHa0bIAS22WKMFtOIquAviLkOyNQyT0_DCUXkd2E53OcRqdEhDfUVSCKsC1CHsMPAKv6VjNGhR6wXUF07Xe7KuZ52G1s_tCdGCG6Q",
                    "width" : 5184
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3840,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAHDbQqs7ehYjfkyARQxQq2PVWnIN6z6Enju8bnTmqUq4_UgDeAigezxyhv4b8QC7tT1F0O-OJuqZbhAqyTlXB1OYO_k0_Y7mk1114ah-BG8PUd84KnRD3CXh7G3wducvWrXtNZkFua-CoFdQG_q8050wUDST5tCWA1VeDvNjkw8pEhDs9E0GxCooxR0A6nn0_BkVGhT3Ub9zxr1PGVQFRV_TecWKzZmiYg",
                    "width" : 5760
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3456,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAP9OkyME0q72GrHkLPkjMoaauPmsYhZBD8wH1qBL_JAEGV8Dhz_6HJcUN_Y64ycfkKzk10COR52XmLerELpEYuxAYG3NHUcfF7Yq0GzEaFcNPIRWa4WgSsnAX5y16im6bvF_KZbW5iuDyX4ET6RW6bgTBwVH-zjAlZYmCI5GXpJ0EhDErfuy0lpX8LKAe8ipjC-BGhQqpZa7Y53HQBQvuIH37jORLeD0hQ",
                    "width" : 5184
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3840,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAEWy_E_dGD3N1ChEdeAzZoNP9mU0JhPEZY4QWf1I0XO73PWM8vmrTA0JjHFsm_qCf6XAmiVgJxPQTNtGTHwYghq7NL91bGYOEIvOLYl5iwxP_RC96zn5hCZnwwp1s4xkzouawNKp0oSCzwpfpUgCQrpplf35QLc1xGj3wsMbTcAbEhCUztajO_mhA0BLHk90mDxSGhRKOzWwFMx7Uhxvqh4afBaKSa6S9g",
                    "width" : 5760
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3000,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116558159141762616471/photos\"\u003ePatrick Chea\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAGWjbZD71nwtfSTA3rRg93F-c_-EyicXxxA8vQ8DSX9hsvDOOCxy8gNUhXF5rDyShtcTm8Gh5qiCGg3xSvA5LDbJiXs7IpGAwAoVTb7_-d4DlNBX0jmkb8tGWdYNkqMo9jTtLr50BY9emgIljAHDaTBrzKlcrgi3Q2rSJM-WnUhaEhC4SwcYYd4Ce2upxRjP8taRGhSsvzcpFjR60jxDLxRlKzhgRIVzWA",
                    "width" : 4000
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 800,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAEu4y0vjM28hn4yFnPz1qWQ0iYysDRPNfY0DiTHlmWMhLI1RfFlWctexo-Gw4iM51yDXo1f2C4eOvN5Gh50ZFfOsfuaLBptwzNYdm9wdBt6Hd5JjiUuEWlVLXo4pKz_62v3ohS2OZfdTJ6Wz5Fw44gVYyA_m9nX3fSCuPp8O2MkMEhCJVvjZOZouIyfIDKFkdg4XGhR8Tgj_y6Tibv548tyMmF5pjB_4VA",
                    "width" : 800
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 3456,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAFG2hBYdpnJYG9DjvY1dnAus3YG89BeKGFx8--e0fwq8OPzCvbQVrXkyiB91KkjnMg8Oum11B4-fHVy6PkuXkat-T9r30PjKNs5KQJTYBWZ-U1SvdQoRx4auOdLzrgNNknVYtUD0fnf6L6MyaJajCvuRJxkd5fhmpM0-qYpwwp24EhCAm-eSSO2TX8lQYa1Vkl41GhR82nfX24T7EoP-xSVKjR-RV5KXYQ",
                    "width" : 3456
                 },
                 {
                    "height" : 5184,
                    "html_attributions" : [
                       "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110980259514072024035/photos\"\u003eMustang Station\u003c/a\u003e"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAALUHiKRI96TGd_7wEGmKlvU2j5WcWVl9B0jYBMBJsHyQLHHTROslXcW9dFTi_7aAK_yTcXOTwMoXJye301W6utyysncbDgPMfOru9YC5BTLpFOSpmpQButZ9Iw75MM8jgf5G-FWEtpnCSRSIAaTCg4yPpJWzdVMZyeFxOn7-wx7-EhAYF5iL9wN3hfqccpCq7DivGhR8mRQFqoyXjq6eUuaCLD2RUMj9LQ",
                    "width" : 3456
                 }
              ],
              "place_id" : "ChIJi3n5orHx7IARQrPTx81AfZU",
              "reference" : "CmRSAAAAwt8fxPAzOX-uQm83_KDcR1Yic89fu-ykEcK2vAJCKS6j1f4_KVCrhoOfQAX8bQd_vXS-k8fEhCQud8JjIhXZBYuIeq3UBfoxhf9zOClHJRi5pstBA21a_FTxP8eyXJ1bEhAMXM_iW_ZlS0LkpOss-b0bGhTVYEqAJEUmeSMUM41wf-1gUBKhCw",
              "reviews" : [
                 {
                    "aspects" : [
                       {
                          "rating" : 2,
                          "type" : "overall"
                       }
                    ],
                    "author_name" : "Spencer Shaw",
                    "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/104561547095341505444/reviews",
                    "language" : "en",
                    "rating" : 4,
                    "text" : "",
                    "time" : 1476463293
                 },
                 {
                    "aspects" : [
                       {
                          "rating" : 3,
                          "type" : "overall"
                       }
                    ],
                    "author_name" : "Joseph Pack",
                    "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/105745544693109977233/reviews",
                    "language" : "en",
                    "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-HJVfdTf8Kf0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABo8/y8qAcuE4h7c/photo.jpg",
                    "rating" : 5,
                    "text" : "",
                    "time" : 1474354270
                 },
                 {
                    "aspects" : [
                       {
                          "rating" : 1,
                          "type" : "overall"
                       }
                    ],
                    "author_name" : "Erik Sandberg",
                    "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/113791312001095793561/reviews",
                    "language" : "en",
                    "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-DH91vW9zE6U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAKiA/Xi3IaYgtIr4/photo.jpg",
                    "rating" : 3,
                    "text" : "",
                    "time" : 1448072416
                 }
              ],
              "scope" : "GOOGLE",
              "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
              "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10771837136305107778",
              "utc_offset" : -480,
              "vicinity" : "Building 65, 1 Grande Ave, California Polytechnic State University, San Luis Obispo",
              "website" : "https://www.calpolydining.com/mustangstation/"
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to add Special Hours in the Places details response:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10145

It looks like Google created a corresponding internal issue #30233280 and is evaluating the feasibility to implement this.

Please star the feature request in the public issue tracker to express your interest and receive updates from Google.